# Export TFS 2010 -Change requests and associated links to Excel

Tags: tfs

How to export Change Request , associated requirement task and associated Tasks to Excel from TFS 2010?
I am trying to write query to pull all CRs and its requirement link and associated task for each requirement. Since i am very new to TFS 2010, i tried with some basic queries but i am getting result with just two levels.
For example, query should return with following  levels

```
ChangeRequest: Name Change
 .RequireMent: First Name Change
   .Task: First Name Change
 .Requirement: Last Name Change
   .Task: Last Name Change
```

Instead i am getting like this(below)

```
ChangeRequest: Name Change
 .RequireMent: First Name Change
 .Requirement: Last Name Change
```

Below screenshot shows my query for "work item type and direct links"
Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Is your question now how to construct the queries or if it is possible to export a "Work Items and Direct Links" query.

Comment: How to construct the queries and export the result to excel with parent-child-child work items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only export parent/child relationships to excel. Excel only support the Flat List and the Tree of Work items. If you export a "Work Items and Direct Links" query, it only exports the parent work items.